# IllegalArgumantException: Unable to find

Tags: android, xpath

I am getting IllegalArgumentException when I try to retrieving Xpath for open the door button in the mobile app. Error message :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to compile '["\/hierarchy\/android.widget.FrameLayout\/android.widget.LinearLayout\/android.widget.FrameLayout\/android.widget.LinearLayout\/android.widget.FrameLayout\/android.widget.FrameLayout\/android.view.ViewGroup\/android.view.ViewGroup\/android.view.ViewGroup\/android.view.ViewGroup\/android.view.ViewGroup[3]"]'. See Cause.
```

This the Xpath for open door button in yaml file :

```
OpenTheDoorButtonXpath: "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[3]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.TextView"
```

Comment: Could you use a shorter XPath ? A not so simplified version could be `//hierarchy//android.view.ViewGroup[3]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.TextView`

Comment: The exception message is saying "See Cause.". Have you checked "Caused By" section? Also show us the particular piece of code where you use that xpath.